# Styling Confirmation Email Identity 2.0 MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, system.net.mail

(Is it possible/Is there a way) to apply html/css styling to the confirmation emails sent by the `SmtpClient` from the `System.Net.Mail` class?

I send emails using the code below:

```
            string html = "Please confirm your account by clicking this link: <a href=\"" + message.Body + "\">link</a><br/>";
            html += HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(@"Or click on the copy the following link on the browser:" + message.Body);
            #endregion

            MailMessage msg = new MailMessage
            {
                From = new MailAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Email"].ToString()),
                Subject = message.Subject
            };
            msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(message.Destination));
            msg.AlternateViews.Add(AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(text, null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain));
            msg.AlternateViews.Add(AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(html, null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html));
            SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", Convert.ToInt32(587));
            System.Net.NetworkCredential credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Email"].ToString(), ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"].ToString());
            smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
            smtpClient.Credentials = credentials;
            smtpClient.Send(msg);
```

Comment: Also there is this, I used it back in the mvc 4 days, worked well http://aboutcode.net/postal/

Comment: @mxmissile thank you. I'll take a look on those.